# Backcolor material-ui textfield depending on value

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I have the following react code which generated textfields based on an array of values, I want to change the backcolor of the textfield based on the value a bound field boolean value

```
array.map((result: IResult, idx: number) =>
                                        <Grid key={idx} item xs={2}>
                                            <TextField
                                                required
                                                variant="filled"
                                                fullWidth
                                                color =   // ?? (if !result.approved set backcolor yellow
                                                id={result.name}
                                                label={result.name}
                                                defaultValue={result.value}
                                                name={result.name} />
                                        </Grid>
```

Comment: backcolor you meant is outline color or the background of the input?

Comment: yes thats what i mean

Comment: outline color, right?

Comment: yes thats would be fine, just something to make it stand out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`color` prop won't help in your case of highlighting input border. I skimmed through [this section (customized input)](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs) and have a solution like below

```js
<TextField
  className={approved && classes.specialCase}
  ...
/>
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: this is exactly what i want, in my code i get the following error  "No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TextFieldProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.

Comment: Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<TextFieldProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-ic0kq?file=/index.js) a working example. Basically you have to do something like this:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <TextField
          required
          variant="filled"
          fullWidth
          color={!result.approved ? "primary" : "secondary"}
          id={result.name}
          label={result.name}
          defaultValue={result.value}
          name={result.name}
        />
</ThemeProvider>
```

As you can see `TextField` element is wrapped into a `ThemeProvider` that provides you `primary` (yellow) and `secondary` (e.g. black) color defined on `theme`.

`theme` is defined like this:

```
const Theme = {
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#FFFF00"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#000000"
    }
 }
};

const theme = createMuiTheme(Theme);
```